# How to set two arrays into textview and checkbox respectively?

Tags: android, arrays, checkbox, textview

I have a set questions in one array and answers in another array.Both the question and answers are in order.The problem is some questions have two options and some have three.

```
questions[]={Can you play cricket? ,Can you play football?,How was the exam?};
answers[]={yes,no,yes,no,easy,tough,hard};
```

I cant know my questions before,I will get it as an array.Somehow i can add questionid to questions and answers.ie

```
questions[]={1.Can you play cricket? ,2.Can you play football?,3.How was the exam?}; 
    answers[]={1.yes,1.no,2.yes,2.no,3.easy,3.tough,3.hard};
```

What I think is comparing two arrays and getting question and answers based on  number 1,2 and 3.In both arrays question number will be common after i add question id.How to solve this.?

Comment: can you tell in one line that what you want exactly ?

Comment: Iterate over these arrays and dynamically create `TextView` and `CheckBox` with array index values.

Comment: @RahulSharma Here two arrays contains common numbers 1,2 and 3.So can i get a new array by comparing two arrays and getting out the question and corresponding answers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an 'Object Orientated' (OOP) approach to this?

For example this could be made trivial using a simple `Question` class:

```
public class Question{
    public String question;
    public List<String> answers;

    public Question(String question, List<String> answers){
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
    } 
}
```

You could then easily iterate over a `List<Question>` and populate a `ListView` as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297840/populate-listview-from-arraylist-of-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array of 2 dimensions for the answers and place them in order so for question number 1 (0) the Array will have [0][0-X] possible answers but in order to use this efficiently, pick up as limit the answer with more possible answers.

You could even mix the order with some Random implementation, but that's up to you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said, you cant know your question before, you can use another array in which you can store your total number of answer of each question, find answer (total number) of each question and use it so you will know exact number of ans.

```
questions[]={1.Can you play cricket? ,2.Can you play football?,3.How was the exam?}; 

answers[]={1.yes,1.no,2.yes,2.no,3.easy,3.tough,3.hard};

ans[]={2,2,3};
```