# How to search in ArrayList of Custom Objects and then Update ListView with results?

Tags: java, android, listview, search, arraylist

I want to make a search from an `ArrayList` of `custom objects` and from those objects populate a `ListView` but I really don't know where to start....

Here's what I've got.

I get the search from a `EditText` and in an `EditorActionListener` I know when to start looking:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {

        //I got this from this site, another question
        int searchListLength = medicos.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
            if (medicos.get(i).getNombre().contains(edittext.getText().toString()))) {
                //This is where Im suposed to do something but I dont know what to use to fill the ListView
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Following is the structure of the `custom object`:

```
public class Medico  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    String nombre, especialidad1,especialidad2,especialidad3,celular,mail,telefono1,telefono2,ext,hospital,direccion;
    double latitud,longitud;
    public Medico(){}
    public Medico(String nombre, String esp1,String esp2, String esp3, String cel,String mail,String tel1,String tel2, String ext,String hospital, String direccion, double lat, double lon){
        this.nombre=nombre;  //and so on.....    
    }

    public void setNombre(String s){
        this.nombre=s;
    }
    public void setEspecialidad1(String s){
        this.especialidad1=s;
    } 

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }
    public String getEspecialidad1(){
        return this.especialidad1;
    }
}
```

and so on.....

Thanks!

UPDATE (Code to update Adapter):

```
public void updatedData(ArrayList<Medico> itemsArrayList) {

        myAdapter.clear(); 

        if (itemsArrayList != null){

            for (Medico object : itemsArrayList) {

                //myAdapter.insert((Medico) object, myAdapter.getCount());
                myAdapter.addAll(object);
                //myAdapter.addAll(itemsArrayList);

            }
        }

        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297840/populate-listview-from-arraylist-of-objects

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that may help when creating the adapter to populate the ListView but I still have trouble to get the current ArrayList of result that will be the source of the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the Adapter that you are using to to populate the ListView.

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {

            //I will store the matches on this list.
            List<Medico> resultado = new ArrayList<Medico>();
            int searchListLength = medicos.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
            if (medicos.get(i).getNombre().contains(searchsds)) {
                // I found a match, I will add it to results
                resultado.add(medicos.get(i));
                }
            }
            //At the end, update the Adapter. I will assume that you have something like this.
            myAdapter.setValues(resultado);
            //You must write the code to set the values on your adapter. If you could post the way you are populating the list view I could help you out with more information.
return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with this code, when refreshing the ListView Im getting all objects again :S

Comment: Are you deleting the previous values from your adapter and setting the new ones?

Comment: I've updated the question with the adapter update code.

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks! (My source is in capital letters so I have to search in capitals too)