# Android: ListView does not show items

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I have simple list from database and want to show just in simple list view.

```
    public class FindAllJobs extends ListActivity {

        private JobOperations operations;
        ArrayList<JobModel> jobs;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_all_jobs);
            operations = new JobOperations(this);
            operations.open();
            jobs = operations.getJobListBySearchKey("python");
            operations.close();
            //ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            //JobAdapter adapter = new JobAdapter(this,jobs);

            ArrayAdapter<JobModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, jobs);
            //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_find_all_jobs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="jobs.find.com.finddevjobs.models.FindAllJobs">


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

But list show always `com.packages.JobModel@dfdfdfdfdfdfdfd`, why?
Where is a mistake? Even created custom adapter but result is the same.
I am new in Android, just first ListView from db:) . Db part works fine.

[image]
This is adapter, but actually it is not finished, I do not understand should I return view or list? :(

```
public class JobAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JobModel> {
    public JobAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JobModel> jobs) {
        super(context, 0, jobs);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        JobModel job = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_find_all_jobs, parent, false);
        }


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Android isn't going to be able to automatically display your `JobModel` in `ArrayAdapter`, because it's trying to just call `.toString()` on your object and display it. Can you post the code you've tried for a custom adapter? That's going to be the way to go. If all you want to do is display a string from each `JobModel`, you could also construct a new list of `Strings` and display that in the `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: I think it's duplicated you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297840/populate-listview-from-arraylist-of-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is, that the ListView gets a List of of Objects. But it don't know how it should name them.
There are 2 solutions to this problem:
**The easy one**
Add the overridden toString() method inside your JobModel and define there what the labeling in the ListView should look like and return this.

Something like this

```
 @Override
 public String toString(){
   return "Name: " + this.getName + "  Date: " + this.getDate();
 }
```

**The complex one that can be modified**
Create a custom ListViewAdapter taking the information your want to display from your JobModel. There are many examples on the internet how create such an adapter.

Comment: ok,  I will try thanks, I expected automatically convert my jobmodel to list view:)))

Answer (score 1):

You must your own adapter and if you want to use default you must pass String object to `ArrayAdapter<String>`.These content that you see in `listview` because of calling `JobModel.toString()`

Comment: ok, now understand the problem :) I expected automatically convert from object to list:)

Comment: yes that's right. you can use this article [listview adapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) @ArmenArzumanyan